# Why aren't 9th commonly added to half diminished chords?

Tags: chord-theory, jazz, performing

I believe that 9ths are not commonly added to half diminished chords. If we wanted to write all the diatonic 7th chords of the E♭ Major scale, with the 9th added, we would have for example on the VI degree the notes C, E♭, G, B♭, D (the 9th), making it a C-9 chord, but the VII degree would be D, F, A♭, C (with no 9th added), becoming D-7♭5.

I understand that any notes are permitted in music, but, why is this common practice? Is this correct?

Comment: Hi David -- I mentioned that I thought it was common practice not adding the 9th because I don't see it very much, but if musicians do play it in a half-diminished chord context, why aren't they written? It has to do with some dissonance avoidance rule like a minor 2nd or tritone? Is there something «slippery» about this 9th?

Comment: It seems like I have heard m9♭5 chords in the wild, and I think that I have occasionally played them, but maybe you are right that they aren't that common. I checked Ted Greene's _Chord Chemistry_, which does not list this chord and says: "the only altered minor chord that is _widely_ used is the m7♭5 type."

Comment: Thanks for the book reference David, I'll check it to learn a bit more about chords. In the meanwhile, if anybody has some explanation why this 9th isn't added, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking at diatonic 7th chords, then the ninth chord built on the 7th degree of E♭ would be **Dm7(♭5♭9)**, which sounds pretty dissonant. The ♭9 is considered an avoid note of the Locrian mode. But **Dm9♭5** can be constructed from the 6th degree of F melodic minor (Locrian #2), which has no avoid notes.

Comment: Also, I did find these in _Chord Chemistry_, after all. I was looking in the wrong place (there are a few thousand chords in there). He lists: **Am7♭5(9)**, **Am7♭5(11)**, and **Am7♭5(9)(11)**.

Comment: That fact that I don't understand this question makes me wonder if it's primarily about jazz theory. If it is, perhaps adding the jazz tag would attract more users who have some insight into the question? If anyone is curious, what I don't understand is why the 9th **would** be added.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "why the 9th would be added" -- for the same reason that a 9th would be added to a minor 7th chord: it sounds nice. In jazz there is a tendency to write simple chord names on lead sheets, and to let players decide which extensions to use, and my suspicion is that this is what is happening here. But maybe there is more to it....

Comment: It started as general question, not related to jazz but to music in general, but perhaps there is a music genre implied - at the time I didn't make that association. I'll add the jazz tag on the question to make it more relevant and play and hear the chords on a piano. If the ♭9 is considered an avoid note of the Locrian mode, are there «rules» that can be followed to define these avoidance notes? What would be the standard to follow? In other words, if you wanted to teach these rules of «dissonance» to somebody, what would you say? What would be the most correct and concise answer?

Comment: Simple rules don't quite make it for describing avoid notes. [This question and the answers might be helpful](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/in-jazz-what-is-an-avoid-note). Better to find a good jazz harmony book, or even better to listen to lots of music and decide for yourself what works.

Comment: For the sake of finding a solution (or at best a definitive answer), I was playing and hearing all the diatonic chords of the E♭ major on the piano and indeed the Dm7(♭5♭9) is more dissonant than the others. Can we say that, if the 9th makes a minor 2nd with the tonic, it should be an avoid note?

Comment: The obvious counterexample is a dominant 7♭9 chord. These are used all the time and sound great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, what you would get is a b9, which is an [avoid note](http://www.mathiaslang.com/2014/11/avoid-notes.html) for *minor* chords, i.e., chords with a minor third (regardless of the 5).

Note that you get the same problem with the III chord (Gm7 in the key of Eb major). Its diatonic ninth would be an Ab, which is the b9, and again it is not used, because also here it is considered an avoid note. So it is not only half-diminished chords that usually will not be played with a b9, but also minor seventh (m7) chords. Of course, in both cases you can decide to use a non-diatonic (major) 9th, but that's a different story.

The only chord type where a b9 is used on a regular basis is the dominant seventh chord, especially if it resolves down a perfect fifth, because there the added tension is desirable.

Comment: Excellent -- I did noticed the same dissonance when adding the 9th to the Gm7 chord in the key of E7 major, but in the half-diminished chord seemed even more harsh, perhaps just my ear. Thank you, Matt, and all that commented, it's clearer now.

Comment: I also discovered in the book "Modern Harmony Step by Step" by Ricky Schneider that indeed the 9th are avoided notes in III- and VII- degrees. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/GEOnKVh.png -- the book mentions in the previous page that a tension is available when it forms an interval of 9 with one of the notes of the chord and not available when it forms one of b9. Could this rule come from classical music?

Comment: @MarcoA.Ferra: I don't know that book, but in practice that rule is not followed. As I've mentioned in my answer and elsewhere, the b9 is definitely available and used a lot with dominant seventh chords. There are also other examples such as major add 4 chords where there's a half step (or a b9) between a chord tone and the tension.