# Avoid Notes in scales

Tags: scales, harmony, jazz

In my understanding, an 'avoid note' in the context of a scale is practically a particular note we should not play , for example during an improvisation, because of the clash (minor 9th interval) it creates with one or more notes of the underlying chord. For example if I'm playing a G7b9 with my left hand, namely F Ab B D, in this case an Avoid note would be the C because of a minor 9th distance from the 3rd. But should I be aware just of minor 9ths intervals or there can be other possible situations?

Comment: What genre are you referring to?

Comment: I'm clearly referring to jazz.. why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Jazz, what is an avoid note?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/in-jazz-what-is-an-avoid-note)

Comment: C is also the 4th of G and that is generally considered an avoid note.  But the fact is anyone can play anything over anything and make it work if they know what they are doing.  The greatest of all time play "avoid notes" all the time in there solos.  And it is NOT clear that you are referring to Jazz.  These ideas go back to classical harmony theory as well.

Comment: @JamesArten there is nothing in this question that indicates clearly that it refers to jazz.  Also, the minor second (equivalently the minor ninth) is often desirable.  It depends on the harmonic context.  There's even one in the G7b9 you're asking about.

Comment: Can't help thinking 'avoid note' is a misnomer. The whole purpose of using notes which 'don't go' is to introduce tension, which then gets resolved. A lot of the time those are 'avoid notes'. Some say that notes which in reality sound fine in some chord voicings are 'avoid notes'. ???

Comment: Kudos Tim. What are often referred to as avoid notes are to me not notes that should be avoided but simply should not be used as target notes or notes to resolve the end of a phrase. A very simple example is  the song “Alfie “, in G the first 5 notes are D C B C D over a G chord. C is an avoid note, right? The 4th degree on a major chord, ouch! It’s even worse than on a G7b9 because at least G7b9 is supposed to have some tension in it. The C is 40% if the notes but in passing to the B and back to the D it is beautiful. This type of phrase has been used in improvisation countless times.

Comment: @ggcg ok but so what are the differences of avoid notes in the context of jazz and classical? Isn’t it always about minor 9th intervals?

Comment: The minor 9th sounds awesome to me.  I put it in the maj7 chord all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Avoid notes" are an idea created by Berklee College of Music's harmony department.

They say that chord tones are the tonic, the third, the fifth, the seventh, and tensions that are a major 9th above a chord tone.

This is not entirely true, since tensions like the b9 and 11 exist on the right scales.

The avoid notes that you're talking about are called melodic avoid notes. If you're playing a G7b9, you'd use a G mixolydian b9 (optional #9) to improvise over it. C would be considered an 11 in a harmonic context, and isn't an "available" chord tone.

If you're looking to have a sound that fits well with the chord, don't sit on the C.